# Jquery Search Suggestion On Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I'm just a beginner in jquery. I want to make a search suggestion for checkbox.

I have this piece of code that suggests searches based on labels

```
function studentFunction() {
   var input, filter, form, label, a, i;
   input = document.getElementById("studentInput");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   form = document.getElementById("studentUL");
   label = form.getElementsByTagName("label");
   for (i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
       a = label[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
       if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
           label[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
           label[i].style.display = "none";

              }
    }
 }
```

I have this piece of code that prints out the checkbox from php to HTML

```
    echo"<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_list[]\" value=\"{$row['UserIndex']} class=\"studentUL\"\"><label><a>{$row['LName']}, {$row['FName']}, {$row['Year']}</a></label>";
```

If I search, it displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVe5v.png)
If i don't search anything, it displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGTG9.png)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're  not closing the `value` tag in your php. Instead of using `\"`, use `'` in the html tags.

Comment: Also you're hiding the label but not the checkboxes. Put all of them inside a `span`.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. I basically enclosed everything with p, and edited my css to have an effect on p.

This is the new code

```
        echo"<p><a><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_list[]\" value=\"{$row['UserIndex']} class=\"studentUL\"\"><label>{$row['LName']}, {$row['FName']}, {$row['Year']}</a></label></p>";
```

And this for the Jquery

```
function studentFunction() {
var input, filter, form, p, a, i;
input = document.getElementById("studentInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
form = document.getElementById("studentUL");
p = form.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    a = p[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        p[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        p[i].style.display = "none";

    }
}
}
```